# Get Google plus number of followers and views in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am integrating Google plus in my APP. I am able to login successfully. I would like to create a profile page. I am able to get name, email address, cover photo, profile picture... Is it possible to get number of followers and views?

I don't see anything related to followers and views in [Person](http://goo.gl/3Tt2H1). Let me know if it is possible if so how?

Answer (score 0):

The number of "followers" is actually circledByCount.

```
public abstract int getCircledByCount()
```

There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=798) to surface views in people.get.

Comment: But I am getting zero always.

Comment: Also how about the views part?

Comment: circledByCount is only present if the page/person has made it public. What userId are you trying to get the count of? Is there a count returned if you try it in the [web docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get)? I answered your question regarding views in the answer.

Comment: I am not trying the webpart. I am trying out in the Android API...currentPerson.getCircledByCount();

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: I am using the currentPerson.. I don't know what do you mean by userId here?

Comment: What is the URL of the page/person that is currently authenticated? The xyz in https://plus.google.com/xyz is the userId.

Comment: Exactly... I am not using any URL...I am using similar to http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: What user are you authenticating as? What user are you authenticating as? What user are you authenticating as?

Comment: Go to plus.google.com/me and sign in with the same account details.

Comment: OK. Using that link. How to get the followers and views?